# NSURLSession URL Response is not cached when larger than a few kilobytes

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, nsurlsession

I am pretty new to programming in IOS with Cocoa and I am using Swift. I fetch data from a JSON API using an NSURLSession data session with custom delegate, not closures. The reason for using custom delegate is that I have to do basic authentication and I also inject a custom cache-control header to control caching behavior (my API doesn’t include any caching related headers in the response at all).

All this works perfectly but only for requests for which the URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData: method is called only once. As soon as I get larger responses (some 20-30kBytes) that call the didReceivedData method several times, the URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler: method doesn’t get called at all, and therefore my response doesn’t get cached. Re-issuing the same request within 5 minutes will issue a request to the server again, which doesn’t happen for requests whose responses only call didReceiveData one single time. The URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: method is correctly called and proceeded in all cases.

The documentation of the URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler: method (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:) says this method is only called if the NSURLProtocol handling the request decides to do so, but I don’t really understand what to do to make this happen.

Any feedback and ideas are very welcome!

This is the code that issues the HTTP request:

```
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.URLCache = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache()
    //config.URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 512000000, diskCapacity: 1000000000, diskPath: "urlCache")

    let urlString = apiUrlForFilter(filter, withMode: mode, withLimit: limit, withOffset: offset)
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var policy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy?
    if ignoreCache == true {
        policy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    } else {
        policy = .UseProtocolCachePolicy
    }

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: policy!, timeoutInterval: 20)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    task.resume()
```

I have the following delegate functions implemented:

- URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: to handle SSL certificate trust,
- URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: to handle basic authentication
- URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler: to read some specific headers and save them as instance variables

additionally, the important ones with code:

URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData: to accumulate data as it arrives for larger HTTP request responses:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    if receivedData == nil {
        receivedData = NSMutableData()
    }
    receivedData!.appendData(data)
    println("did receive data: \(receivedData!.length) bytes")
}
```

URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler: to inject my own Cache-Control header:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, willCacheResponse proposedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSCachedURLResponse!) -> Void) {
    println("willCacheResponse was called")

    let response: NSURLResponse = proposedResponse.response
    let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
    var headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields

    var modifiedHeaders = headers        
    modifiedHeaders.updateValue("max-age=300", forKey: "Cache-Control")
    let modifiedResponse = NSHTTPURLResponse(URL: httpResponse.URL!, statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode, HTTPVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: modifiedHeaders)
    let cachedResponse = NSCachedURLResponse(response: modifiedResponse!, data: proposedResponse.data, userInfo: proposedResponse.userInfo, storagePolicy: proposedResponse.storagePolicy)
    completionHandler(cachedResponse)
}
```

URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: to check the complete response for errors and call a callback closure this class gets by initialization to further proceed the result data:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()

    if error != nil {
        var string: String?
        if errorString != nil {
            string = errorString
        } else {
            string = Helpers.NSURLErrorDomainErrorForCode(error!.code)
        }
        errorCallback(string!)
        return
    }

    if receivedData == nil {
        errorCallback("the query returned an empty result")
        return
    }

    var jsonError: NSError?
    let results: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)

    if results == nil {
        errorCallback("the data returned was not valid JSON")
        return
    }

    let jsonParsed = JSONValue.fromObject(results)

    if let parsedAPIError = jsonParsed!["error"]?.string {
        errorCallback("API error: \(parsedAPIError)")
        return
    }

    callback(jsonParsed!, self.serverTime!)
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the NSURLSession cache delegate called only when Cache-Control header present in HTTP response. Please request the server team to inject the Cache-Control header from server side. It may work.

Comment: This may be, but it is still a bit strange that if the response is small enough to come back with all data within one callback, the caching actually works nicely using my self-injected headers, but if the response takes several callbacks, it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try using your custom NSURLCache (in your code it is commented)? Because the linked Apple documentation now says it will only be cached when "The response size is small enough to reasonably fit within the cache. (For example, if you provide a disk cache, the response must be no larger than about 5% of the disk cache size.)"

Comment: @ChristianAnton I'm seeing similar behavior where my session delegate willCacheResponse method is never called. However, when I subclass URLCache the storeCachedResponse and getCachedResponse methods _are_ called. Did you ever figure out what the issue is?